# What's the package name for using de2bi in octave?

Tags: software-installation, octave

I'm trying to use`de2bi` in Octave but it seems that the package isn't installed. 
To install it, I should use this command:

```
pkg install -forge <package_name>
```

I don't know the package name, could you help me?

Comment: What Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package search [says](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=de2bi) that this function is contained in `octave-communications-common` deb-package.

You can install it for all users using

```
sudo apt-get install octave-communications-common
```

or use [*communications* package](https://gnu-octave.github.io/packages/communications) for your user.